# How can I center multiline text in the horizontal remainder of a page?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I'd like to produce a bunch of pages in the 'minicard' format (2.75 by 1.1), with a 1-inch qr code taking up one side of the thing, and centered multiline text on the other side.

[image]

Unfortunately, I don't have a handle on vertical centering. My current approach uses the 'm' column type, which supposedly centers text vertically, but that isn't happening:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[margin=.05in,papersize={2.75in,1.1in}]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}
\renewcommand\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{p{1in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.65in} |}
\hline
\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1in]{600px-QR_code_Wikimedia_Commons_(URL).png} 
& unique key a 
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

A solution would be wonderful, but I'd settle for an explanation. Should I even be using a table?

Comment: first post :) I wasn't able to insert a pair of images, but they seemed necessary to get my point across, so they've been code'd out.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! You need some more rep before able to include images so that they show automatically (I suspect this is a spam countering measure). I've included the images so that they show up in the post for you `:-)`

Comment: Put your image inside this macro `\raisebox{-1cm}{\includegraphics[.... }` which might give you an idea why this is happening :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in the package, as described here: [Vertical alignment in table: m-column, row size - problem in last column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68732/vertical-alignment-in-table-m-column-row-size-problem-in-last-column/68748#68748)

You can use the tweak in your case too. You ought to increase the dimesions a bit to get rid of the warnings and to get everything settled correctly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove `[demo]` in your case
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[margin=.05in,papersize={2.79in,1.12in}]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}
\renewcommand\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{m{1.02in} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.65in} |@{}m{0pt}@{}}
\hline
\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1in]{600px-QR_code_Wikimedia_Commons_(URL).png} 
& unique key a 
&\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```