# tabular can't vertically align the cell to the top

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|m{1cm} | @{}m{0pt}@{}}
    \hline
        1-1 & 1-2&\\[1cm]
        \hline
        2-1 & 2-2 &\\[1cm]
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Had to use a hack to make the last column align middle:

[Vertical alignment in table: m-column, row size - problem in last column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68732/vertical-alignment-in-table-m-column-row-size-problem-in-last-column)

Wikipedia says:

> 1. p{'width'} --- paragraph column with text vertically aligned at the top
> 2. m{'width'} --- pragraph column with text vertically aligned in the
>    middle (requires array package)

So I inspected the 1-st column to be top aligned, and the 2-nd to be middle aligned. But instead, both columns are middle aligned:

[image]

How to make the 1-st column cells top aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want?  I seem to recall that David Carlisle once said that the alignment parameters apply to the alignment with respect to other matter *in that cell*, not, as you were hoping, with respect to matter in adjacent cells.

What I did here is add buffer space above and below each data entry.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|m{1cm}|m{1cm} | @{}m{0pt}@{}}
    \hline
        \addvbuffer[0.0cm 0.9cm]{1-1} & \addvbuffer[.5cm]{1-2}&\\
        \hline
        \addvbuffer[0.0cm 0.9cm]{2-1} & \addvbuffer[0.5cm]{2-2} &\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|>{\vspace{.5cm}}p{1cm}<{\vspace{.5cm}}|}
    \hline
        1-1 & 1-2\\
        \hline
        2-1 & 2-2\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In your original your paragraph entries are only single line so it is hard to spot the difference between `p` and `m` the `p` makes the reference point be on the baseline of the first line (like `\parbox[t]`) and `m` makes the reference point be at the vertical centre offset by the math axis height, (like `\parbox[c]`) So on a single line entry this only slightly lowers the entries in the second column.

Comment: I like you solution better than mine.  @user4035 I won't be offended if you re-award the accepted answer to Dr. Carlisle.