# How to change table row heights and center their contents?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, height, dcolumn

How can I decrease(or increase) the row height of a specific row in a table and center its content both horizontally and vertically?

A [related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/24167) discusses how to decrease the height of a row, but how can I center the text in that table cell? I am using `dcolumn` as a column type therefore cannot use any other columns type which does the centering.

```
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{L}{D{.}{.}{1.1}}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|L|}
\hline
a & b & 1.1\\ [-5pt]
\hline
d & e & 2.2 \\ [1pt]
\hline
g & h & 3.3 \\ [6pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I want an output similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE, so we can see what types of entries you are working with.

Comment: Where is the `dcolomun`?

Answer (score 3):

A very basic approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{L}{@{\hspace{1.5em}}D{.}{.}{1.1}@{\hspace{1.5em}}}
\newcolumntype{V}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3em}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

\begin{document}

%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|V|V|L|N}
\hline
a & b & 1.1 &\\
\hline
d & e & 2.2 &\\[15pt]
\hline
g & h & 3.3 &\\[35pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Notes:

1. I've redefined your column type `L` adding some space at the left and at the right.
2. I've defined a standard `array` column type `V` for the remaining columns (it is possible since `dcolumn` loads `array`).
3. I've defined an invisible column type `N` to avoid the problem described here: [Vertical alignment in table: m-column, row size - problem in last column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68732/vertical-alignment-in-table-m-column-row-size-problem-in-last-column).
4. I've commented out `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}`.

Comment: Compiling the document with `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019)` displays the shown table but cells are not vertically center aligned.