# Increase LaTeX table row height

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

How does one increase the height of the rows in a LaTeX table?

Comment: Just one more question how to place the text in the middle but increasing the height.

Comment: Instead of adjustments to `\extrarowheight` just modify `\arraystretch`, e.g. by `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}`.

Comment: @Werner This question has one of the clearest titles I've ever seen. What's the need to close it after a year?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use package `easytable`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\begin{document}

\begin{TAB}(r,1cm,2cm)[5pt]{|c|c|}{|c|c|c|}% (rows,min,max)[tabcolsep]{columns}{rows}
hi & tall one    \\
hi & medium one  \\
hi & standard one\\
\end{TAB}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Can you also help in this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159259/latex-table-adjustments?noredirect=1#comment363655_159259

Comment: done. See answer

Comment: But I want one that can automatically span width, and break pages, and ... (My point is that I should have to use a different environment to modify row spacing ;-) )

Comment: What is `r` here?

Comment: I would like to add this documentation to this answer:
https://www.ctan.org/pkg/easytable

Answer (score 184):

To increase the row height in a table you can either increase the `\extrarowheight` through something like

```
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
```

or stretch the row through something like

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
```

as Thorsten Donig points out in the above comment.

IMHO, the best way to increase the height and keep the vertical alignment is to add the space when you break the row with `\\`, for example with `\\[5pt]`.

This is an example (I've exaggerated a little with `50pt` here)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|M{4cm}|M{4cm}|N}
\hline
\textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} &\\[50pt]
\hline
text & text&\\[50pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that I've added a column as the last one defined as `@{}m{0pt}@{}` to avoid the issue described here: [Vertical alignment in table: m-column, row size - problem in last column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68732/vertical-alignment-in-table-m-column-row-size-problem-in-last-column).

Output

[image]

Comment: I prefer the `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}`.  I did not see how to use the other method and still set the horizontal alignment, i.e., l/c/r.

Comment: @stvn66 For left alignment, define `\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}` and, for right, `\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}`

Comment: Unfortunately, the author-preferred solution doesn't work at all, at least not on my machine. 112 upvotes got me and I tried to incorporate this thing without trying. I hope that other people see this comment before trying it out in their work, and try the solution to see if it works at all, despite >100 votes on it.

Comment: Using \newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}} to create an extra 'null' cell is an ingenious idea. Works well

Comment: This is great: `\\[5pt]`

Comment: should I put `[5pt]` beginning of the row as well to make the text centered?

Comment: @alper I added \vspace{5pt} in the first column and then it works. Otherwise, it doesn't work, at least in my latex environment.

Answer (score 119):

## Super Simple Solution

<sub>I faced similar problem, & found a (not so conventional but) simple way to solve it. Wish, it will help others too.</sub>

---

I had a table like this-

```
\begin{tabular}{c|ccc}
$x$ & 1 & 2 & 3\\ \hline
$f(x)$ & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{tabular}
```

And, I wanted to put some extra space before the second row-

[image]

So, I inserted an extra empty line-

```
\begin{tabular}{c|ccc}
$x$ & 1 & 2 & 3\\ \hline 
\\
$f(x)$ & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{tabular}
```

But, now I had put too much space there-

[image]

So, I used negative line spacing to reduce it-

```
\begin{tabular}{c|ccc}
$x$ & 1 & 2 & 3\\ \hline 
\\[-1em]
$f(x)$ & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{tabular}
```

Great! everything was perfect-

[image]

Comment: I really like this solution because it's simple and easy to control. One note is that if you have vertical lines between your other columns you have to add "&&&" as many times as it takes so that the vertical lines connect down.

Comment: To complete the comment above: avoid disconnection of multiple vertical lines by using: `&&&\\[-1em]`

Comment: I appreciate this very simple answer, but it resulted in gaps in the vertical lines separating columns. How do I fix this?

Comment: The arraystretch solution keeps the vertical bars looking normal: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31681/192461

Comment: Anyone knows how to make this horizontally?

Comment: Has anyone noticed the double (thicker) vertical line on the second row? This solution may be easy but far from elegant and perfect...

Answer (score 29):

Use `\rule{0pt}{value}` to change the single row height to **value**.

[Source](http://www.sascha-frank.com/Faq/tables_four.html)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554661/250119  for an example where it's used.