# Tabular header vertical align and row height

Tags: tables

How can I vertical align the header content (Electric Field) in my tabular, and eventually increase his row height?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

\newcommand{\tr}[1]{#1 &\\[22pt]}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{ |M{4cm}|M{4cm}|N }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Electric Field} \\
  \hline
  \tr{Point charge & $\vec{E} = \dfrac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \cdot \dfrac{q}{r^3} \times \vec{r}$}
  \hline
  \tr{Electric dipole & $\vec{E} = \dfrac{1}{2 \pi \epsilon_0} \cdot \dfrac{\vec{p}}{r^3}$}
  \hline
  \tr{Charged ring & $\vec{E} = \dfrac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \cdot \dfrac{q\vec{z}}{\sqrt{(r^{2}+z^{2})^3}}$}
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}`

Answer (score 2):

The following MWE contains two suggestion: The first uses invisible rules to increase the row height of only the first row, while the second is an alternative approach using `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` from the `booktabs` package while avoiding all vertical lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}
\newcommand{\tr}[1]{#1 &\\[22pt]}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{ |M{4cm}|M{4cm}|N }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2em}Electric Field\rule[-1em]{0pt}{2em}} \\
  \hline
  \tr{Point charge & $\vec{E} = \dfrac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \cdot \dfrac{q}{r^3} \times \vec{r}$}
  \hline
  \tr{Electric dipole & $\vec{E} = \dfrac{1}{2 \pi \epsilon_0} \cdot \dfrac{\vec{p}}{r^3}$}
  \hline
  \tr{Charged ring & $\vec{E} = \dfrac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \cdot \dfrac{q\vec{z}}{\sqrt{(r^{2}+z^{2})^3}}$}
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{M{4cm}M{4cm}N }
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\rule{0pt}{2em}Electric Field\rule[-1em]{0pt}{2em}} \\
  \midrule
  \tr{Point charge & $\vec{E} = \dfrac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \cdot \dfrac{q}{r^3} \times \vec{r}$}
  \tr{Electric dipole & $\vec{E} = \dfrac{1}{2 \pi \epsilon_0} \cdot \dfrac{\vec{p}}{r^3}$}
  \tr{Charged ring & $\vec{E} = \dfrac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \cdot \dfrac{q\vec{z}}{\sqrt{(r^{2}+z^{2})^3}}$}
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For further information on how to change the row heights, you can also have a look here: [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/134144) and here: [Increase LaTeX table row height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159257/134144)

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution with `cellspace`,  which lets you define minimal vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you use `siunitx`). You won't have to define this `\tr` command for the spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}S{m{#1}}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

\newcommand{\tr}[1]{#1 &\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |M{4cm}|M{4cm}|N }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|Sc|}{Electric Field} \\
  \hline
  Point charge & $\vec{E} = \dfrac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \cdot \dfrac{q}{r^3} \times \vec{r}$ & \\
  \hline
  Electric dipole & $\vec{E} = \dfrac{1}{2 \pi \epsilon_0} \cdot \dfrac{\vec{p}}{r^3}$ \\
  \hline
  Charged ring & $\vec{E} = \dfrac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \cdot \dfrac{q\vec{z}}{\sqrt{(r^{2}+z^{2})^3}}$ & \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `bigstrut` package or define your own strut as `\mystrut{<length in pt>}` for example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcommand{\mystrut}[1]{$\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{0pt}{#1pt}}}$}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}    
\begin{tabular}{|M{4cm}|>{$}M{4cm}<{$}|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Electric Field\mystrut{30}}                                                                 \\ \hline
  Point charge\mystrut{30}    & \vec{E} = \dfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \cdot \dfrac{q}{r^3} \times \vec{r}           \\ \hline
  Electric dipole\mystrut{30} & \vec{E} = \dfrac{1}{2\pi \epsilon_0} \cdot \dfrac{\vec{p}}{r^3}                    \\ \hline
  Charged ring\mystrut{30}    & \vec{E} = \dfrac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \cdot\dfrac{q\vec{z}}{\sqrt{(r^{2}+z^{2})^3}} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}    
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]