# Vertical Centering in Tables

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertically center some text inside a table. From [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159260) (and other) answer(s), the following example *should* work...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|M{4cm}|M{4cm}|N}
\hline
\textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} &\\[50pt]
\hline
text & text&\\[50pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In the linked answer it produces the desired output. What's funnier is even on *my other device*, it produces the desired output. It's only on this one laptop that I'm getting this:

[image]

The only difference is that I'm using the portable version of MikTex on this device, but I can't work out what's going on. The fact that it works on another device but not on this one is really quite bothering...

Comment: from time of writing of the answer on your link the package `array` was upgraded. changed are code for `m` column specifier ... consequently this solution doesn't work anymore on the way as you expected. test your mwe with the following replacement for the first row with for example with `\textbf{Text} & \textbf{Text} & \rule{0pt}{50pt}\\ ` and observe difference. or put longer text in one cell and you will see, that text will be vertical centered.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting - so I guess my other computer is also using an outdated version of the package? Do you know if the replacement would work with the older version of the package? I sync files between the two devices and versioning might become an issue :(

Comment: it should. you need to load `array` as `\usepackage{array}[=2016-10-06]` (not tested).

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modifying the definition of the `N` column type with the help of `makecell` yields more or less what you want, I think:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}>{\Gape [30pt] [30pt]{}}m{0pt}@{}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|M{4cm}|M{4cm}|N}
\hline
\textbf{Text} &\textbf{Text} & \\
\hline
text & text & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. Would there be a way to keep each row height of the table customisable? It seems like this would enforce the same height across the entire table

Comment: In this table, the `\Gape{30pt}{30pt}` command adds  30 pt at the top and the bottom of an empty cell. You can change the values for top and bottom (independently).