# Better margins in tabular's cells containing math-mode

Tags: tables, math-mode

I have this code

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass[utf8]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
            \hline
            & Weighting & Cost (\$)         \\ \hline
            \multirow{5}{*}{Material costs}       & 0           & $[10000,\,\infty[$  \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 1.25 & $[7500,\,10000[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 2.5 & $[5000,\,7500[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 3.75 & $[2500,\,5000[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 5 & $[0,2500[$ \\ \hline
            \multirow{5}{*}{Labor costs} & 0           & $[40000,\,\infty[$  \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 1.25 & $[30000,\,40000[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 2.5 & $[20000,\,30000[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 3.75 & $[10000,\,20000[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 5 & $[0,10000[$ \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Scale for the cost of the project}
        \label{tab:project_cost}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

It produces this:

[image]

As you can see, the margins in the cells are way too small. We can even say it's non existent, so it's really hard to see the brackets (`[`)

How can I increase the margins?

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159260/156344.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case a simple `\arraystretch` redefinition suffices.

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass[utf8]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
            \hline
            & Weighting & Cost (\$)         \\ \hline
            \multirow{5}{*}{Material costs}       & 0           & $[10000,\,\infty[$  \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 1.25 & $[7500,\,10000[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 2.5 & $[5000,\,7500[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 3.75 & $[2500,\,5000[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 5 & $[0,2500[$ \\ \hline
            \multirow{5}{*}{Labor costs} & 0           & $[40000,\,\infty[$  \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 1.25 & $[30000,\,40000[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 2.5 & $[20000,\,30000[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 3.75 & $[10000,\,20000[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 5 & $[0,10000[$ \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Scale for the cost of the project}
        \label{tab:project_cost}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL APPROACH**

I just added a `>{}` directive to a column that adds a `\strut` that has been padded by `2pt` above and below.  Requires `array` package for the `>`-directive functionality, and `stackengine` to pad the `\strut` by `2pt`.

*However, the OP noted that this approach combined with the `\multirow` causes the first column to not be vertically centered.*

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass[utf8]{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow,stackengine}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\addstackgap[2pt]{\strut}}l|c|c|}
            \hline
            & Weighting & Cost (\$)         \\ \hline
            \multirow{5}{*}{Material costs}       & 0           & $[10000,\,\infty[$  \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 1.25 & $[7500,\,10000[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 2.5 & $[5000,\,7500[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 3.75 & $[2500,\,5000[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 5 & $[0,2500[$ \\ \hline
            \multirow{5}{*}{Labor costs} & 0           & $[40000,\,\infty[$  \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 1.25 & $[30000,\,40000[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 2.5 & $[20000,\,30000[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 3.75 & $[10000,\,20000[$ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 5 & $[0,10000[$ \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Scale for the cost of the project}
        \label{tab:project_cost}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The "Material costs" and "Labor costs" aren't centered anymore.

Comment: @Vinccool96 You are right.  Let me think on this one (I don't use a lot of `multirow`)

Comment: @Vinccool96 See revision

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility with `cellspace`, which defines a minimal vertical padding for cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`):

```
\documentclass[utf8]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htp]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|>{$}Sc<{$}|>{$}Sc<{$}|}
            \hline
            & \text{Weighting} & \text{Cost (\$)} \\ \hline
            \multirow{5}{*}[-12pt]{Material costs} & 0 & [10000, \infty[ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 1.25 & [7500, 10000[ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 2.5 & [5000, 7500[ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 3.75 & [2500, 5000[ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 5 & [0,2500[ \\ \hline
            \multirow{5}{*}[-12pt]{Labor costs} & 0 & [40000, \infty[ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 1.25 & [30000, 40000[ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 2.5 & [20000, 30000[ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 3.75 & [10000, 20000[ \\ \cline{2-3}
            & 5 & [0,10000[ \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Scale for the cost of the project}
        \label{tab:project_cost}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another clipboard manager accident… Fixed. Thank you so much!