# Discontinuous table border line appearing while using tabular

Tags: tables, hline

I was trying to increase the thickness of the cell by giving extra space at the bottom of cell but that gives me discontinuos line at the table border. How can I get rid of this. Solution using only the tabular package is preferrable.

[image]

Here is what I have tried

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | }
\hline
Feature&Result\\\hline
Number of Observations&51,717\\ \\ \hline 
Number of Variables&17 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Regarding table row height see: [Increase LaTeX table row height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159257/134144)

Comment: But I said I don't want to use any package for this. Can you explain this using tabular

Comment: `Number of Observations&51,717\\ &\\ \hline ` Just add the missing `&` in the row of the empty line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem why the line isn't continuous is because the rule is actually drawn by the cell to its left. If you don't have a cell there, no rule is drawn. So to get that rule, you'd have to place an empty cell there:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | }
\hline
Feature&Result\\\hline
Number of Observations&51,717\\ & \\ \hline 
Number of Variables&17 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks skillmon it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the thickness of cell without getting discontinous line, one way could be to use \rule for every cell.

```
\rule{0pt}{0.9cm} Feature&Result\\\hline
\rule{0pt}{0.9cm} Number of Observations&51,717\\ \hline 
\rule{0pt}{0.9cm} Number of Variables&17 \\\hline
```

Comment: To increase the height of every row without a package, you can use `\def\arraystretch{1.1}` (or any other value greater than 1).

Comment: Yes but it is asymmetric. `Cellspace` is better.