# Manually adjust length and width of table (Cells)

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

Question:

In the following table i would like to adjust length and height of every cell, how can i do this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} \cline{7-8} \cline{10-11} \cline{13-14}
        (1) &  &  & (5) &  &  & (9)  &  &  & (13) &  &  & (17) &  \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} \cline{7-8} \cline{10-11} \cline{13-14} 
        (2) &  &  & (6) &  &  & (10) &  &  & (14) &  &  & (18) &  \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} \cline{7-8} \cline{10-11} \cline{13-14} 
        (3) &  &  & (7) &  &  & (11) &  &  & (15) &  &  & (19) &  \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} \cline{7-8} \cline{10-11} \cline{13-14} 
        (4) &  &  & (8) &  &  & (12) &  &  & (16) &  &  & (20) &  \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} \cline{7-8} \cline{10-11} \cline{13-14} 
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To adjust the width of the cells, you can use `p{<your width}` type columns (or `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{<your width>}` for the horizontally centered version). See also here: [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703/134144). For adjustments of the row height, see here: [Increase LaTeX table row height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159257/134144)  and [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/134144)

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but maybe you are interested in simplifying teh coda a bit. Instead of one large tabular with a lot of `\cline` commands, you could also use five adjacent `tabular`s as follows:  `\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
(1) & \\
\hline
(2) & \\
\hline
(3) & \\
\hline
(4) & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\quad
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
(5) & \\
\hline
(6) & \\
\hline
(7) & \\
\hline
(8) & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}`.

Comment: With this, you could even use a counter to automatically number the rows. See for example here: [Automatic table row numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21245/134144)

Comment: Agree with use of \hline command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in my previous comments, I'd split up the single table into five different tables. This will make the code much longer but (at least in my opinion) a lot more readable and easier to adjust.

In the following example, I have also used the [automated row numbering approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21245/134144). I have also introduced a new, centered fixed width column type. In order to increase the row height, I have added the `makecell` package in combination with its `\makegepedcells` command. Laslty, I made sure, the five tables fit into the textwidth by using `\hfill` inbetween them.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{makecell} % For increased row height using \makegapedcells

%%%%% Atomatic rownumbering from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21245/134144 
\usepackage{array,etoolbox}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
%%%%% 

\newcommand\rn{\makebox[2.5em][c]{(\rownumber)}}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}
\setcellgapes{6pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|@{\rn}|P|}
\hline
  \\
\hline
  \\
\hline
 \\
\hline
 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{|@{\rn}|P|}
\hline
 \\
\hline
 \\
\hline
 \\
\hline
 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{|@{\rn}|P|}
\hline
 \\
\hline
 \\
\hline
 \\
\hline
 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{|@{\rn}|P|}
\hline
 \\
\hline
 \\
\hline
 \\
\hline
 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{|@{\rn}|P|}
\hline
 \\
\hline
 \\
\hline
 \\
\hline
 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can of course adjust the width of the column containing the number to your liking by changing teh width of the `\makebox`. By changing the width in the definition of the `P` type cell, you can change the width of the second column. By adjusting the value of `\setcellgapes` you can influence the height of the rows.

In the following screenshot, I have used:

```
\newcommand\rn{\makebox[2em][c]{(\rownumber)}}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.25cm}}
\setcellgapes{10pt}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this exactly what i want. Thanks a lot......