# Can you adjust the height of a table?

Tags: tables

I want to fit in a table in the blank space, but the table's height is slightly bigger than the gap. So is there a way to reduce or increase the height of the whole table?

Comment: Sure. Please show a minimal compilable example so that people here can help.

Comment: Also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159257/increase-latex-table-row-height for related information.

Comment: `\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.9}` probably works (put it just before the begin tabular