# equation vertical alignment in tabular, baseline is too low

Tags: tables, equations, align, vertical-alignment, amsmath

I want to know how to precisely configure the vertical alignment of equations in tabular, for example, `\arraystretch` can increase the height but cannot make equations vertically centered, their baseline is too low. Also, inline equations and display-style equations can be both well aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\arraystretch{2.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        $a + b = c$ & inline style \\
        \hline
        $e + \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} + \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y} + \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}z} = 0$ & display style \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {Q[c, mode=math] l},
                 rowsep  = {5pt}
                 }
a + b = c   &   inline style          \\
e + \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} + 
    \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y} + 
    \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}z} = 0
            &   display style       \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A solution with the `cellspace` package, which allows to define a minimal vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C`if you load `siunitx`, or any letter you please with a loading time option). I also loaded the `esdiff` package to simplify the code for derivatives in Leibniz notation.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{esdiff}
    \usepackage{cellspace}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|}
            \hline
            $a + b = c$ & inline style \\
            \hline
            $e + \diff{f}{x} + \diff{f}{y} + \diff{f}{z} = 0$ & display style \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

An answer with `easytable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{TAB}(r,1cm,2cm)[5pt]{|c|c|}{|c|c|}% (rows,min,max)[tabcolsep]{columns}{rows}
        $a + b = c$ & inline style \\
        $e + \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} + \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y} + \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}z} = 0$ & display style \\
    \end{TAB}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159263/120578

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`arraystretch` causes asymmetric stretching. This effect is more visible the higher is its factor. It's better to use struts to add vertical spacing in rows

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator\od{\mathrm{d}\!}


\begin{document}
\bgroup
\centering
\[
  \begin{array}{| c | c |}
    \hline
    \xmathstrut{0.5}
    a + b = c                  & \textrm{inline style} \\
    \hline
    \xmathstrut{1.25}
    e + \dfrac{\od f}{\od x}
    + \dfrac{\od f}{\od y}
    + \dfrac{\od f}{\od z} = 0 & \textrm{display style} \\
    \hline
  \end{array}
\]
\egroup
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a key `cell-space-limits` for address that problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|}[cell-space-limits=6pt]
        \hline
        $a + b = c$ & inline style \\
        \hline
        $e + \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} + \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y} + \dfrac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}z} = 0$ & display style \\
        \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]