# Vertical tablecell alignment fail for the last one

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, height

Using array m{} to vertically align cells in a tabular, and changing row height with \\[] the last cell is not properly aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|m{.3\linewidth}|m{.3\linewidth}|m{.3\linewidth}|}
  \hline
  A & B & C \\[1cm]
  \hline
  1 & 2 & 3 \\[2cm]
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Can't understand why. Any idea?

Comment: Here is the answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68732/34618

Comment: The main question was why, not how to :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you could say only the last is aligned: If you add a final column you get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|m{.3\linewidth}|m{.3\linewidth}|m{.3\linewidth}|@{}c@{}}
  \hline
  A & B & C& \\[1cm]
  \hline
  1 & 2 & 3& \\[2cm]
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

where you can see that `\\[1cm]` adds space by adding a strut with *depth* which reacts rather strangely with `m` columns, especially of the added strut is actually in teh `m` column (ie if you have an m column as a final column.) It's usually better if you can avoid the length argument of `\\` and instead use `\arraystretch` and/or `\extrarowheight` to increase the spacing.

Comment: One drawback using \arraystretch is that it does not modify the height and the depth of a row symmetrically, so that the content of a cell is no more vertically centred. If centring is important, it may be better, in my opinion, to use the `cellspace` package and its `\cellspace[top/bottom]limit` lengths.