# Increase tabular row height and vertical align to center

Tags: tables

I am trying to reproduce the result of this answer:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167022/25764

However, I do not get the same results when I type the same.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|C{3cm}|L{4cm}|C{3.5cm}|N}
\hline
\textbf{\textit{fine/coarse}} & \textbf{Property} & \textbf{\textit{lamellar/equiaxed}} &\\[20pt]
\hline
x/x & Elastic Modulus & x/+ &\\[20pt]
\hline
+/- & Strength & -/+ &\\[20pt]
\hline
+/- & Ductility & -/+ &\\[20pt]
\hline
+/- & Fatigue crack initiation & -/+ &\\[20pt]
\hline
-/+ & Fatigur crack propagation & +/- &\\[20pt]
\hline
+/- & Oxidation Behaviour & +/- &\\[20pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:eomsomeprops}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is the expectation:
[image: Expected Result]

This is what I get:

[image: whatIget]

Note that, the cell heights are proper, but they are not centered vertically.
I am using miktex on windows.

What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using of the `tabularray` package the MWE is very simple and short:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
 
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {c l c},  %{Q[c, wd=3cm] Q[l, wd=4cm] Q[c, wd=3.5cm]}
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, c},
             rowsep=3ex,
             }
\textit{fine/coarse}    & Property                  &   \textit{lamellar/equiaxed}  \\
x/x                     & Elastic Modulus           & x/+       \\ 
+/-                     & Strength                  & -/+       \\
+/-                     & Ductility                 & -/+       \\
+/-                     & Fatigue crack initiation  & -/+       \\
-/+                     & Fatigur crack propagation & +/-       \\
+/-                     & Oxidation Behaviour       & +/-       \\
    \end{tblr}
    \label{table:eomsomeprops}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily obtain what you want with the `cellspace` package, which lets you define minimal vertical spacings at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`).  Here is a possible code:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{cellspace}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3.5ex}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2ex}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}S{m{#1}}}
    \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}S{m{#1}}}
    \newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|C{3cm}|L{4cm}|C{3.5cm}|N}
    \hline
    \textbf{\textit{fine/coarse}} & \textbf{Property} & \textbf{\textit{lamellar/equiaxed}} &\\[20pt]
    \hline
    x/x & Elastic Modulus & x/+ &\\[20pt]
    \hline
    +/- & Strength & -/+ &\\[20pt]
    \hline
    +/- & Ductility & -/+ &\\[20pt]
    \hline
    +/- & Fatigue crack initiation & -/+ &\\[20pt]
    \hline
    -/+ & Fatigur crack propagation & +/- &\\[20pt]
    \hline
    +/- & Oxidation Behaviour & +/- &\\[20pt]
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:eomsomeprops}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired effect by vertically stretching a table. Simply add `\renewcommand\arraystretch{<factor>}`, something like `3.0`. Because stretching this way is not quite symmetric, a remedy is to reduce upper space via `\setlength\extrarowheight{<v-length>}`, e.g. `-3pt`.

[image]

Another solution, similar to `\\[20pt]` is to define a strut

```
\newcommand\mystrut{\rule{0pt}{30pt}}
```

which you add at the end of each row, right before `\\`, for instance

```
x/x & Elastic Modulus & x/+ & \mystrut\\
```

but IMO it causes unnecessary clutter.

---

The solution based on the `arraystretch`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3.6}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{-3pt}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|C{3cm}|L{4cm}|C{3.5cm}|N}
        \hline
        \textbf{\textit{fine/coarse}} & \textbf{Property} & \textbf{\textit{lamellar/equiaxed}} & \\
        \hline
        x/x & Elastic Modulus & x/+ &\\
        \hline
        +/- & Strength & -/+ &\\
        \hline
        +/- & Ductility & -/+ &\\
        \hline
        +/- & Fatigue crack initiation & -/+ &\\
        \hline
        -/+ & Fatigur crack propagation & +/- &\\
        \hline
        +/- & Oxidation Behaviour & +/- &\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table:eomsomeprops}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```