# Why is the second column of my tabu not vertically aligned to the middle?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabu

I'm trying to create a SWOT (strengths, weaknesses, opportunities, threats) table, which is a basic 4x2 table. The cells that aren't part of the header will contain itemized text. All cells have to be vertically and horizontally aligned to the center.

I've managed to get it nearly working, as such:

```
\begin{tabu}{|X[c,m]|X[c,m]|}
\tabucline- 
\rowfont{\bfseries} \cellcolor[HTML]{009925} STRENGTHS & \cellcolor[HTML]{D50F25} WEAKNESSES \\[5pt]
\tabucline- 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Hello
    \item This is an item
    \item This is another item
\end{itemize} 
&
\begin{itemize}
    \item Hello
    \item This is an item
    \item This is another item
\end{itemize} \\
\tabucline- 
\rowfont{\bfseries} \cellcolor[HTML]{3369E8} OPPORTUNITIES & \cellcolor[HTML]{EEB211} THREATS \\[5pt] 
\tabucline- 
\begin{itemize}
    \item Hello
    \item This is an item
    \item This is another item
\end{itemize} 
&
\begin{itemize}
    \item Hello
    \item This is an item
    \item This is another item
\end{itemize} \\ 
\tabucline- 
\end{tabu}
```

This outputs the following table:

[image: LaTeX output]

The headers of the second column are not vertically aligned (like with the first). However, the itemize of the second column are vertically aligned, which leads me to think I've made a small mistake. However, I can't manage to figure out what the issue is. Please help.

Comment: Could be the same problem as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68732/vertical-alignment-in-table-m-column-row-size-problem-in-last-column Edit: the suggested workaround seems to solve the problem for your example as well.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That fixed it, wow. Had no idea it was a bug. Thanks!

Comment: wreckingcode: If your problem is solved can we close this as a duplicate?