# Vertical alignment of table text

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align my table text vertically:

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,pifont,xcolor}
\newcolumntype{C}[3]{@{\hspace*{#1}}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#2}@{\hspace*{#3}}}
\newcolumntype{R}[2]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}@{\hspace*{#2}}}
\newcolumntype{L}[2]{@{\hspace*{#1}}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#2}}
\newcommand{\fajfka}{\textcolor[RGB]{0,166,79}{\ding{51}}}
\newcommand{\krizek}{\textcolor[RGB]{237,27,35}{\ding{55}}}
\newcommand{\degC}{$^\circ$C}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  |R{70pt}{5pt}
  *{9}{|C{0pt}{20pt}{0pt}}|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|C{6pt}{70pt}{0pt}|}{\textbf{\o\,\,= 2mm}} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & \textbf{v} \\[4pt]
  \cline{1-10}
  300\degC & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka \\[4pt]
  \cline{1-9}
  290\degC & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka \\[4pt]
  \cline{1-9}
  280\degC & \krizek & \krizek & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka \\[4pt]
  \cline{1-9}
  270\degC & \krizek & \krizek & \krizek & \krizek & \krizek & \krizek & \krizek & \krizek \\[4pt]
  \cline{1-9}
  \textbf{t {[}\degC{]}} \\[4pt]
  \cline{1-1}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: table]

As seen, last visible column cell resp. last visible row cells are not vertically centered. Those can be also centered only if there are visible some other cell borders in those column, row.
How can I vertically center text in every visible cell?

Comment: use `p` not `m` or use a final `&\multicolumn{1}{}\\` to make an empty cell with no rule rather than leave the row short with a `m` cell at the end

Comment: basically I think this is a duplicate of this question, see Frank's answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68732/vertical-alignment-in-table-m-column-row-size-problem-in-last-column/174166#174166

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`m` columns and `[..]` argument to `\\` work in well specified ways, but they don't work well together or how people always expect. I'd avoid both here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,pifont,xcolor}
\newcolumntype{C}[3]{@{\hspace*{#1}}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#2}@{\hspace*{#3}}}
\newcolumntype{R}[2]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}@{\hspace*{#2}}}
\newcolumntype{L}[2]{@{\hspace*{#1}}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#2}}
\newcommand{\fajfka}{\textcolor[RGB]{0,166,79}{\ding{51}}}
\newcommand{\krizek}{\textcolor[RGB]{237,27,35}{\ding{55}}}
\newcommand{\degC}{$^\circ$C}
\begin{document}

{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{
  |R{70pt}{5pt}
  *{9}{|C{0pt}{20pt}{0pt}}|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|C{6pt}{70pt}{0pt}|}{\textbf{\o\,\,= 2mm}} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & \textbf{v} \\
  \cline{1-10}
  300\degC & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka \\
  \cline{1-9}
  290\degC & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka \\
  \cline{1-9}
  280\degC & \krizek & \krizek & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka & \fajfka \\
  \cline{1-9}
  270\degC & \krizek & \krizek & \krizek & \krizek & \krizek & \krizek & \krizek & \krizek \\
  \cline{1-9}
  \textbf{t {[}\degC{]}} \\
  \cline{1-1}
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using the `\diameter` symbol from `wasysymbol` would look better, in my opinion (exists in boldmath).