# Vertical Centering

Tags: tables

The following LaTeX code produces a table with one row and three columns. Each cell contains two short words word-wrapped so that one name is above the other. A design requirement of this table is the ability to force a word-wrap on a short sentence and control cell padding.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{2pt}}m{1cm}}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
        \begin{tabular}{|M|M|M|}
            \hline
            Sue Tim &  Sam Jake &  Eddy John  \\[3ex]
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This code will produce the following output:

[image]

The problem here is that the last cell is not vertically centered like the other two cells. Vertical padding is controlled by `\\[3ex]` on line 8 while horizontal padding is controlled by `m{1cm}` on line 3.

How can I modify this code so that the last cell looks like the first two cells?

Comment: THis is a duplicate (it's a kind of "feature"  of `m` alignment but a workaround was posted, I'll find it...

Comment: see Frank's answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68732/vertical-alignment-in-table-m-column-row-size-problem-in-last-column