# Trouble with a table in latex

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a table using the following code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}\hline \\
Test users  &  Operating system & Browser & Screen resolution\\ \\ \hline
Test user 1 & Win 7 pro & Mozilla firefox & 1680X1050\\ \hline
Test user 1 & Win 7 pro & Mozilla firefox & 1680X1050\\ \hline
Test user 1 & Win 7 pro & Mozilla firefox & 1680X1050\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Test environment details}
\label{Test-environment-details}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

What I get from this is shown below:
[image]
Why the vertical lines missing in column 2,3 and 4? Thanks

Comment: you have `\hline \\ ` and `\\ \\ `  so those table rows are cut short with just the first column, don't do that.

Comment: Unrelated but don't use `[h!]` laTex will usually warn about this and change it to `!ht]` but using `[htp]` is better, otherwise it is just increasing the chance that the table floats to the end of the document.

Comment: Also unrelated do not put a `center` environment around `table` it will have no effect on the alignment but will produce anomolous vertical space at that point even though the table may float and be set wheresoever else.

Comment: Regarding ur first comment. What do you recommend? I am trying to put an empty line up and below the content of first row. I am trying to make it as a header.

Comment: you could get rid of the vertical lines and use `booktabs` package `\toprule` and `\midrule` which have vertical space around them, or you could use `\\[.5em]` to add space after a row, to add space after an \hline` is a bit harder perhaps add something like `\rule{0pt}{2cm}` into the first cell, or whatever height you need

Comment: Also note that you can use `$1680 \times 1050$` to typeset your screen resolutions more nicely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way to get the table as you'd like it is

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}\hline & & &  \\
        Test users  &  Operating system & Browser & Screen resolution\\ & & &  \\ \hline
        Test user 1 & Win 7 pro & Mozilla firefox & 1680X1050\\ \hline
        Test user 1 & Win 7 pro & Mozilla firefox & 1680X1050\\ \hline
        Test user 1 & Win 7 pro & Mozilla firefox & 1680X1050\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test environment details}
    \label{Test-environment-details}
\end{table}
```

You have to add the & to separate the cells even if you want a blank line. Otherwise the vertical lines will not be drawn for these rows.

[image: result]

As @David Carlisle recommended, the [booktabs](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) package allows to typeset tables with a nicer spacing. I usually use booktabs for all formal tables. A MWE would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabular}{llll}\toprule
        Test users  &  Operating system & Browser & Screen resolution\\ \midrule
        Test user 1 & Win 7 pro & Mozilla firefox & 1680X1050\\
        Test user 1 & Win 7 pro & Mozilla firefox & 1680X1050\\
        Test user 1 & Win 7 pro & Mozilla firefox & 1680X1050\\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Test environment details}
    \label{Test-environment-details}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here's how to obtain the table you wanted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{tabular}{|m{1.8cm}|m{2.8cm}|m{2.5cm}|m{2.8cm}|@{}m{0pt}@{}}
\hline 
Test users  &  Operating system & Browser & Screen resolution &\\[15pt]\hline
Test user 1 & Win 7 pro & Mozilla firefox & 1680X1050 &\\ \hline
Test user 1 & Win 7 pro & Mozilla firefox & 1680X1050 &\\ \hline
Test user 1 & Win 7 pro & Mozilla firefox & 1680X1050 &\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Test environment details}
\label{Test-environment-details}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some comments:

- I've used a fixed-width column specifier (`m`) instead of your `l`. This permits you to have vertically centered cells.
- The last column (`@{}m{0pt}@{}`) is needed to avoid the issue described here: [Vertical alignment in table: m-column, row size - problem in last column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68732/vertical-alignment-in-table-m-column-row-size-problem-in-last-column).

Comment: Thanks but can you please explain what is going on here `\begin{tabular}{|m{1.8cm}|m{2.8cm}|m{2.5cm}|m{2.8cm}|@{}m{0pt}@{}}` :)

Comment: @ρss Of course. Added some comments (I was on the rush...)