# Multirow verticle text centering on the last column

Tags: vertical-alignment, multirow

I have scoured other articles trying to find a way to vertically align the last column in a multirow table in the middle. Without luck, no matter what I have tried the text will not budge. The code has now gotten to a 'hacked' stage where if I remove objects the table dies (so I apologise for that!).

I've defined

Does anyone have any suggestions?

My current code is as follows:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\newcolumntype{A}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{3.5cm} }
\newcolumntype{B}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{5cm} }
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{1.5cm} }
\newcolumntype{D}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{2cm} }
\begin{tabular}{|A|B|C|D|D|}
\hline \textbf{Risk Description} & \textbf{Consequences} & \textbf{Severity} & \textbf{Likelihood} & \textbf{Risk} \\
\hline \hline
\multirow{2}{3.5cm}{\centering High pressures at depth}&\multirow{2}{5cm}{\centering Damage to camera’s electrical system.}&\multirow{2}{1.5cm}{\centering 9}& High Risk 4 & High Risk 36 \\[2ex]
\cline{4-5}
& & & Low Risk 3 & Low Risk 27 \\
[2ex]\hline

\multirow{2}{3.5cm}{\centering Leaks in camera housing}&\multirow{2}{5cm}{\centering  Damage to camera’s electrical system.}&\multirow{2}{1.5cm}{\centering 9}& High Risk 4 & High Risk 36 \\[2ex]
\cline{4-5}
& & & Low Risk 3 & Low Risk 27 \\
[2ex]\hline

\multirow{2}{3.5cm}{\centering Poor visibility in turbid water}&\multirow{2}{5cm}{\centering Cameras are unable to see targets and video feed quality suffers.}&\multirow{2}{1.5cm}{\centering 6}& High Risk 7 & High Risk 42 \\[2ex]
\cline{4-5}
& & & Low Risk 3 & Low Risk 18 \\
[2ex]\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I haven't used LaTeX for long, so my knowledge base for fixing this is quite limited. Thank you for helping in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug which has already been mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68732).

However, you could try to rewrite your table to use some other approach as you do not need the `m`-column at all. I did that for your table as it would be most pleasing imho.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}\toprule
        \textbf{Risk Description} & \textbf{Consequences} & \textbf{Severity} & \textbf{Likelihood} & \textbf{Risk} \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{2}{3.5cm}{\centering High pressures at depth}&\multirow{2}{5.2cm}{\centering Damage to camera's electrical system.}&\multirow{2}{*}{9} & High Risk 4 & High Risk $36$ \\
        & & & Low Risk 3 & Low Risk 27 \\\addlinespace      
        \multirow{2}{3.5cm}{\centering Leaks in camera housing}&\multirow{2}{5.2cm}{\centering  Damage to camera's electrical system.}&\multirow{2}{*}{9}& High Risk 4 & High Risk 36 \\
        & & & Low Risk 3 & Low Risk 27 \\\addlinespace      
        \multirow{2}{3.5cm}{\centering Poor visibility in turbid water}&\multirow{2}{5.2cm}{\centering Cameras are unable to see targets and video feed quality suffers.}&\multirow{2}{*}{6}& High Risk 7 & High Risk 42 \\
        & & & Low Risk 3 & Low Risk 18 \\\bottomrule    
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I usually avoid `multirow`; here's a different implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,calc}

\newcommand{\multicell}[3][\centering]{%
  \makebox[#2]{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}>{#1\arraybackslash}p{#2+2\tabcolsep}@{}}
    #3
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\newcolumntype{A}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{3.5cm} }
\newcolumntype{B}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{5cm} }
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{1.5cm} }
\newcolumntype{D}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} p{2cm} }

\begin{tabular}{|A|B|C|D|D|}
\hline
\textbf{Risk Description} & \textbf{Consequences} & \textbf{Severity} & \textbf{Like} & \textbf{Risk} \\
\hline \hline
High pressures at depth &
  Damage to camera’s electrical system. &
  9 &
  \multicell{2cm}{High Risk 4 \\\hline Low Risk 3} &
  \multicell{2cm}{High Risk 36 \\\hline Low Risk 27} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]