# tex4ht produces funny characters in table (TL 2023 only)

Tags: tables, tex4ht

I noticed `tex4ht` generates funny characters now in table when surrounding table with `\begin{small}...\end{small}` and at same time using `p-width` as option. This happens only in TL 2023. Here is an MWE and command to reproduce it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{small}
\begin{tabular}[c]{|p{0.9in}|l|c c c c c c c c|}\hline
1& Optimal&Rubi&MMA&Maple&Maxima&Fricas&Sympy&Giac&Mupad\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{small}
\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
make4ht  -ulm default -a debug foo.tex "mathjax,htm,nostyle,p-width"
```

Gives

[image]

During compilation it says

```
INFO]    make4ht-lib: parse_lg process file: foo.htm
[WARNING] domfilter: DOM parsing of foo.htm failed:
[WARNING] domfilter: ...ive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/span) [char=1256]
```

Two ways to fix this, Either remove the `p-width` option, or remove the `\begin{small}....\end{small}`. So this MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[c]{|p{0.9in}|l|c c c c c c c c|}\hline
1& Optimal&Rubi&MMA&Maple&Maxima&Fricas&Sympy&Giac&Mupad\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And using same exact command to compile gives

[image]

The above happens only in `TL 2023`. I tested it under `TL 2022` and it works OK in both cases.

Why does this happen? I use `p-width` all the time, there is [reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249179/tex4ht-how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns) and this is first time I see this problem.   Btw, replacing `\begin{small}...\end{small}` with `\small ....\normalsize` does *not* fix the problem. So this MWE still gives the same problem in `TL 2023`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\small 
\begin{tabular}[c]{|p{0.9in}|l|c c c c c c c c|}\hline
1& Optimal&Rubi&MMA&Maple&Maxima&Fricas&Sympy&Giac&Mupad\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\normalsize
\end{document}
```

[link tex4ht bug tracking.](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?614)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the fact that the `p-width` option wrongly handles font sizes that contain decimal points. The small font, in your case is `10.95`, and this causes the error.

Try this configuration file, it uses the FP library from LaTeX 3, which seems to fix this issue:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \Configure{HColWidth}
     {\ifnum\HRow=1% output CSS only on the first row, to prevent duplication
      \tmp:dim=\fp_to_dim:n{\dim_to_fp:n{\HColWidth}/\f@size}
      \Css{\#TBL-\TableNo\space td:nth-child(\HCol)% CSS selects ID of the current table column
          {width:\strip@pt\tmp:dim em;}}
     \fi}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michal. This seems to have fixed it on the small tests I did now.