# Vertical alignment of the last column in tabular, math mode

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have seen other posts related to this issue, but I haven't been able to vertically center the last column of my table:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}} 
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash$}m{#1}<{$}}

%_________________________________


\begin{document}

    \rowcolors{1}{gray!5}{gray!15}

    \begin{tabular}{M{1cm} M{1cm} M{1cm}}
        a&b&c\\[14pt]
        u&v&w\\[14pt]
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Apparently, `(\centering)\arraybackslash` isn't the solution here.

**Edit:**

I don't know if this is the way to go, but I'll edit my question in response to CarLaTeX's answer. What I'm ultimately trying to do is

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}} 


\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{gray!5}{gray!15}
\begin{tabular}{L L}
    %
    (1+x)^{\alpha}
    &=1+ \alpha x+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!}x^{2}+\cdots+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}x^{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{n+1}\right)
    \\[14pt]
    %
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}
    &=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3}{8}x^{2}-\cdots+(-1)^{n}\frac{1\times 3\times\cdots.\times.(2n-1)}{2\times 4\times\cdot\times 2n}x^{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{n+1}\right)
    \\[14pt]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

but vertically centered. Following CarLateX's suggestion regarding the minimum width of the columns,

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
    mymatrix/.style = {
        matrix of math nodes, 
        nodes={inner ysep=7pt, minimum width=4cm, text height=2ex, text depth=.75ex},
        every odd row/.style={nodes={fill=gray!5}},
        every even row/.style={nodes={fill=gray!15}},
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
        inner sep=0pt
    },
}

\begin{document}




    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[mymatrix]{
    (1+x)^{\alpha}
    &=1+ \alpha x+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!}x^{2}+\cdots+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}x^{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{n+1}\right)
    \\
    %
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}
    &=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3}{8}x^{2}-\ldots+(-1)^{n}\frac{1\times 3\times\ldots\times(2n-1)}{2\times 4\times\ldots\times 2n}x^{n}+\mathcal{O}\left(x^{n+1}\right)
    \\  };
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

for example. But, of course, I don't want the 1st column to be as long as the second.

Also, how would I flush the text to the left of the nodes? Using anchor=west, well, anchors the node rather than the text.

Comment: This code  produces all column cells vertically centred. There must be something else.

Comment: Are you saying that this code should work, or that it does? Because, pasting it in overleaf yields the same thing:https://www.overleaf.com/15745639rpywqvtqgwdb#/59901105/

Comment: For me, it works as expected. I even downloaded the  Overleaf code and it compiles fine. Would there be a problem with Overleaf?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68732/vertical-alignment-in-table-m-column-row-size-problem-in-last-column/174166#174166

Comment: note that this is fixed in current versions 2017-11-07  Frank Mittelbach  <Frank.Mittelbach@latex-project.org>

 * array.dtx: fixed bug reported on stack exchange SX68732 about
 bad vertical placement with last column being an m-column

Comment: Okay, Frank Mittelbach's answer goes way beyond what I am able to understand. The patch that he provides does fix the alignment issue, but then the rowcolor command gets nullified :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a very big strut:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{$\bigggstrut}l<{$}}
\newcommand{\bigggstrut}{\vphantom{\left|\vbox to 18pt{}\right.}}


\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{gray!5}{gray!15}
\begin{tabular}{LL}
(1+x)^{\alpha}
&=1+\alpha x+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!}x^{2}+\dots
   +\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\dots(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}x^{n}
   +\mathcal{O}(x^{n+1})
\\
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}
&=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3}{8}x^{2}-\dots
  +(-1)^{n}\frac{1\times 3\times\dots\times(2n-1)}
                {2\times 4\times\dots\times 2n}x^{n}
  +\mathcal{O}(x^{n+1})
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you could try a TikZ `matrix of math nodes`.

Maybe you'll have to adjust the `text width` or other options like `text height` and `text depth` according to the actual content of the cells.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
    mymatrix/.style = {
        matrix of math nodes, 
        nodes={
            inner ysep=7pt,
            inner xsep=0pt,  
            text height=4ex, text depth=2ex
        },
        column 1/.style={nodes={text width=4em, align=right}},
        column 3/.style={nodes={text width=30em, align=left}},
        every odd row/.style={nodes={fill=gray!5}},
        every even row/.style={nodes={fill=gray!15}},
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
        inner sep=0pt
    },
}


\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[mymatrix]{
        (1+x)^{\alpha}
        &{}={}& 1 + \alpha x + \dfrac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!}x^{2} + \dotsm + \dfrac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\dotsm(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}x^{n} + \mathcal{O}\left(x^{n+1}\right)     \\
        \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}
        &{}={}& 1 - \dfrac{x}{2} + \dfrac{3}{8}x^{2} - \cdots+(-1)^{n}\dfrac{1\times 3\times\dotsm\times(2n-1)}{2\times 4\times\dotsm\times 2n} x^{n} + \mathcal{O}\left(x^{n+1}\right) \\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. But if you type 'text text text' instead of say 'b', although the cell will adjust, the one beneath it won't. Any work around?

Comment: @Chris You have already other very good answers, however, I edited my answer to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Off topic: I am fairly new to posting here, so, if you'd know: should I undo my previous edit so as to make the question more concise, or keep its 'history'?

Comment: @Chris No, leave it as is. It's OK :)

Answer (score 2):

with `array` and `rule` as `strut` on the end of the each table row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{gray!5}{gray!15}
\[
    \begin{array}{r@{\;} l<{\rule[-2em]{0pt}{4.5em}}}
(1+x)^{\alpha}
    & = 1 + \alpha x + \dfrac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!}x^{2} + \dotsm + \dfrac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\dotsm(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}x^{n} + \mathcal{O}\left(x^{n+1}\right)     \\
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}
     & = 1 - \dfrac{x}{2} + \dfrac{3}{8}x^{2} - \cdots+(-1)^{n}\dfrac{1\times 3\times\dotsm\times(2n-1)}{2\times 4\times\dotsm\times 2n} x^{n} + \mathcal{O}\left(x^{n+1}\right)
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]