# problem with new array.sty, colortbl.sty, and tabu.sty

Tags: tables, spacing, tabu, colortbl

This is a follow up to [new array.sty and colortbl.sty incompatibility?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429272/87678)

The problem is that with the current version of `array.sty` the `\\[5mm]` is ignored. The solution provided in the linked question fails to give the right output in other ways.

The MWE example in the linked question led to a solution for the `tabular` environment and `colortbl.sty`. But my actual table uses `tabu.sty`.

For the moment I can work around by using an earlier version of `array.sty`, but would prefer something more permanent. (I have many `tabu` environments in my documents and find its syntax easy for my purposes.)

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{|l|X|}
  \hline
  Row 1 & \\
  \hline
  Row 2 & \\[5mm]
  \hline
  Row 3 & \\[5mm]
  \hline
  Row 4 & \\[5mm]
  \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your example gives the expected output if I use the patched version of colortbl from David in your other question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Ah. I copied the wrong version. It needs an `X` column.

Comment: Another one for @DavidCarlisle. It breaks with tabularx too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see this gets fixed by the suggested corrections for array and colortbl https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/42.

So pending further tests that should get resolved with ctan updates in a few days.