# "Use of \@startpbox doesn't match its definition." Error on a Table

Tags: tables, color

I am getting the following error during compilation "Use of @startpbox doesn't match its definition." for all my tables in tabular and tabularx environment.

The relevant portions of my document include:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} %Reason for the error
\usepackage{geometry,tabularx,multirow}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{l c p{6cm}}
\textbf{Name} & : &  \\
\textbf{Registration Number} & : &  \\
\textbf{Department} & : & Civil Engineering \\
\textbf{Date of Joining} & : &  \\
\textbf{Date of Upgradation (if any)} & : &  \\
\textbf{Specialization/Stream} & : & \\
\textbf{Area of Research}  & : &  \\
\textbf{Category of Admission} & : &  \\
\textbf{Guide} & : &  \\
\textbf{Co-Guide(s)} & : & \\
\textbf{Date of DC Meetings} & : & \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This error occurred after I updated all the packages. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And after updating?

Comment: sorry. after updating. before it was working fine.

Comment: Which version of `colortbl` do you have installed? Can you show us your .log file?

Comment: colortbl 2018/05/02 v1.0c Color table columns (DPC)

Comment: Update again. The current version is colortbl 2018/12/12

Comment: not working. I tried updating from miktex but it is not updating any package.

Comment: You need to update as user and and as admin.

Comment: I have the similar problem, but the solution presented in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429272/new-array-sty-and-colortbl-sty-incompatibility doesn't help. The issue occurs when using p{width} column spec or tabularx.

Comment: Thanks @Ulrike Fischer. In my case, I updated the admin but not the user part of MikTeX.