# colortbl is ignoring \\[] in tabular (MiKTeX, Windows 7)

Tags: colortbl

In the following sample code, the 10pt row separation is ignored if I use the colortbl package. I know this has been an issue and was reported last year and apparently it was fixed. I am running MiKTeX with the latest updates. My version of colortbl is 1.0d Tue Dec 18 13:34:14 2018. I also did a full update of Miktex to make sure I had the latest packages. Are there any other packages, other than colortbl, I need to make sure that are fully updated?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

 \usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}
3.4 \\[10pt]
5.6 \\[10pt]
7.8 \\[10pt]
9.0
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

With colortbl:

[image]

Without colortbl

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to outdated software, solved with an update

Comment: I just want to add that it took we a couple of hours to figure this one out. It was only because I found a clue in another StackOverflow question that I realized one had to update MiKTeX in admin and user mode. For a newbie, this would not be obvious. Hence I decided to include the answer here. You are free to delete if need be, as I know now how to correctly update MiKTeX in future.

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out after getting the following error on my full project file after I updated everything: "Use of @startpbox doesn't match its definition.”  and going to:

["Use of \@startpbox doesn't match its definition." Error on a Table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466857/use-of-startpbox-doesnt-match-its-definition-error-on-a-table?noredirect=1)

The solution is to do MiKTeX updates in administrator and user modes. The MiKTeX console lets you select user or admin mode. Select each in turn and install updates.