# Using \newcolumntype definition together with colortbl package

Tags: tables, arrays

I just upgraded my Miktex distribution and I am not able to compile my MNWE example (see below)

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{array}
  % tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703 
  \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
  \newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
  \usepackage{tabularx} 
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{colortbl}   % comment this line before compile
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|x{6cm}|}
      \(a + b\)  & first equation description    \\ %\midrule
      \(a - c\)  & second equation description   \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

When I comment line with `\usepackage{colortbl}` then everything works fine. It seems that I have same problem discussed in question:
[new array.sty and colortbl.sty incompatibility?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429272), but this question is dated 2018-04-30. I've updated my distribution every month. I'm not able to find out where the error is.

```
\listfiles:
 *File List*
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   array.sty    2018/11/13 v2.4j Tabular extension package (FMi)
tabularx.sty    2016/02/03 v2.11b `tabularx' package (DPC)
 amsmath.sty    2018/12/01 v2.17b AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
   color.sty    2016/07/10 v1.1e Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  luatex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for luatex
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

I don't understand why I have colortbl.sty with version 2012/02/13 v1.0a. It seems to me, that update process in Miktex didn't work properly in my installation.

In next step, I try to look into installation folder and I am really surprised, because package colortbl is placed in:

- c:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\colortbl\colortbl.sty

and also

- c:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\colortbl\colortbl.st

I guess I discovered the wheel again .... Can I delete ..\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX folder?

Comment: There was a bug in `colortbl` or code redesign recently. Try to update more than once a month.

Comment: I did the update today.

Comment: Your example runs for me with `colortbl` activated, in Linux with TL 2018, daily updated. Adding `\listfiles` just before `\begin{document}`, I get (amongst other entries)  **colortbl.sty    2018/12/12 v1.0d Color table columns (DPC)**, i.e. the latest version is from 2018/12/12

Comment: Compiles for me. Did you update as user and as admin?

Comment: show your log file, you will most likely find that your array or  colortbl have not been updated

Comment: As mentioned, both your [`array`](//ctan.org/pkg/array) (current: v2.4k; yours: v2.4j) and [`colortbl`](//ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) (current: v1.0d; yours: v1.0a) packages are out-of-date.

Comment: I guess the wheel is on each end of axle one labelled user and other labelled admin and they pull in two different directions one towards room 101 **a** and the other towards room 101 **d** ?

Comment: @jafan: If the file is in AppData, it's a local update. Find MiKTeX Package Manager in your Start Menu, right-click on it and choose "Run As Administrator", then update all the packages.