# m{} column in tabular doesn't center text in third(last) column

Tags: tables, columns

This is such a simple thing and should just work, but I don't understand why it is not. I have a simple table with three columns and two rows. I wanted the text in each cell in the first row to be vertically centered. It does center[image] vertically in the first and second columns, but in the third column, the text remains at the top. My source is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\title{}
\author{}
\pagestyle{empty}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|m{1cm}|m{4in}|m{3cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Particulars} & \textbf{Amount}\\[8pt]
\hline
1. & Blah blah blah &  2,000.00\\[8pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I almost feel sorry to have to ask this here, as it is such a simple thing. But, it gives me a less than satisfactory result, and I don't seem to be able to make out what is going wrong.

Comment: On my system, I get a different result, but I'd suspect the manually added space (`\\[8pt]`) to be the culprit.

Comment: do you have an old system the handling of m in the last column was fixed in 2017

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Vertical alignment in table: m-column, row size - problem in last column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68732/5764)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manually adding vertical space to the rows, I'd suggest using `cellspace`. You can adjust the spacing to suit your needs, while the contents will be vertically centered.

Personally, I prefer tables with a more open look (no vertical lines and less horizontal lines), so I added an example with `booktabs` as well. Lastly, you could also use the `siunitx` package to help with the aligment of number in table cells. If your second column sontains quite some text, I'd go for `tabularx` in order to make the table as wide as the textwidth while allowing automatical linebreaks in the second column.  I have included an example on this as well.

Lastly, and if you'r tired of manually numbering rows, you can take a look at [Automatic table row numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21245/134144)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}


\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{\cellspacetoplimit}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-ignore={,},input-decimal-markers={.}}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

With cellspace:

\begin{tabular}{|0{m{1cm}}|0{m{4in}}|0{m{3cm}}|}
\hline
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Particulars} & \textbf{Amount}\\
\hline
1. & Blah blah blah &  2,000.00\\
\hline
2. & Blah blah blah &  2,000.00\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

With booktabs:

\begin{tabular}{m{1cm}m{4in}m{3cm}}
\toprule
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Particulars} & \textbf{Amount}\\
\midrule
1. & Blah blah blah &  2,000.00\\
2. & Blah blah blah &  2,000.00\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

With booktabs, siunitx and tabularx:

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXS[table-format=4.2]}
\toprule
{No.} & {Particulars} & {Amount}\\
\midrule
1. & Blah blah blah &  2,000.00\\
2. & Blah blah blah &  2,000.00\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `\arraystretch` instead of add some  `\extrarowheight` plus `[8pt]` to each row:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.6}
\begin{tabular}{|m{1cm}|m{4in}|m{3cm}|}\hline
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Particulars} & \textbf{Amount}\\\hline
1. & Blah blah blah &  2,000.00\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

(... and of course, instead of jailed tables, use `booktabs`!).

Comment: Just to confirm that the added space at the end of each row with [8pt] seems to be what caused the problem. It worked fine without that and with \arraystretch added to increase the space.