# Reason for unexpected vertical displacement in tabular?

Tags: tables

The following minimal example doesn't do what I expect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{40mm}p{60mm}}\label{blah}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

I don't understand why the b is displaced upward. If I remove the label, the problem goes away. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Try removing the label. Anyway, there's no table environment, hence no table counter.

Comment: @Bernard: I want to be able to refer to the table by page number, just like if I put a label in any random piece of text. Is there some reason why it needs to be placed somewhere else, like outside the table, to avoid this vertical space?

Comment: ...we've had this before somewhere...

Comment: @BenCrowell - For `\label` to work, LaTeX has to be able to associate the argument of `\label` with a counter. The `\caption` command, when used inside a `table` (not `tabular`) environment, increments a counter called `table`. If you place `\label` after `\caption`, LaTeX will make the correct connection. In contrast, your particular use of `\label` is guaranteed to achieve nothing useful -- and, in fact, mess things up in unexpected ways. Interestingly, if one embeds your `tabular` environment (*sans* the `\label` directive) inside a `table` environment, the problem vanishes.

Comment: Thanks, all. Moving the label outside the tabular does work. @Mico: *In contrast, your particular use of \label is guaranteed to achieve nothing useful* Again, as I explained in the earlier comment to Bernard, this does achieve something useful. I want to be able to refer to the page number where the material occurs. In case this is still causing confusion, my text where I refer to it is something like this: "We now apply the system of mathematical analogies described on p.~\pageref{blah}."

Comment: So it seems to me that this is a plain old bug in latex. It does something totally wrong in what is I suppose an unexpected use case. I don't see any reason why a \label{} command should ever change the rendered output.

Comment: @BenCrowell - You wrote, "I want to be able to refer to the page number where the material occurs". Fortunately, you can achieve this noble goal *without* placing a `\label` instruction in a place where it doesn't belong. I guess viewpoints will diverge on whether or not the issue you've encountered is a bug. Knuth has memorably stated that he never intended TeX to be *cracker-proof*. If you insist on taking LaTeX in directions that were never intended to be taken -- congratulations. you may call yourself a certified LaTeX cracker.

Comment: @BenCrowell: See [Vertical alignment in table: m-column, row size - problem in last column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68732/5764)

Comment: @Mico it is definitely not a bug more a documented feature (you see the same with other things, notably `\color`)  and so long as you don't need `\ref` it's Ok to use `\label` here. By design it does something more or less sensible even if no counter is active.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `\label` somewhere safer:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\hrule

\begin{tabular}{p{40mm}p{60mm}}\label{blah}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{tabular}


\hrule

\begin{tabular}{p{40mm}p{60mm}}
a\label{blah2} & b \\
c & d
\end{tabular}

\hrule

\begin{tabular}{p{40mm}p{60mm}}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{tabular}\label{blah3}

\hrule

\end{document}
```

A `\label` is not like `\typeout` that simply writes to the terminal it has to delay the writing to the aux file until the page number is known. The resulting write node is in many ways like a box of height and width 0pt and that is the effect that you see on the layout: the parbox (vtop) is aligning on the first node in its vertical list which is the invisible write node.